# How do I display an image returned from MVC4 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We have a Web API (MVC4) application that returns images from the database. I have verified that the call to the Web API does produce a valid image.

Here is the Fiddler result showing that the image is returned properly: [image: Fiddler API Call]:

I tried setting an image element with the same source as the call, but that didn't work:

```
<img id="img" src="http://localhost/Seek/api/artifactcontent/?userName=XXXXX&password=XXXXXX&id=15-00931-27" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You request in Fiddler is a POST request; the `<img>` tag sends a GET request. If you want to display images using `<img>` tags, you'll need to make your action accept GET requests instead of (or in addition to) POST.

Comment: OK great! Can I make the same `Post` action accept `Get`, or do I need to create another action called `Get` and have both actions call the function that returns the image?

Comment: The same action can accept both verbs - you can use the `[AcceptVerbs]` attribute: `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]`

Comment: Yes, `[AcceptVerbs]` work, as long as you have routes which can map to the action with that attribute.